cannot yum update i want to install firefox
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream':

Status code: 404 for http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 147.75.93.85)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried


CENTOS Linux 8 is end of life. That means that the vendor will not help you. This includes downloads for updates and questions on this forum. https://www.centos.org/centos-linux-eol/

If you open the site http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/ you will read next:

This directory tree doesn't contain any supported/maintained release !
For CentOS Stream 9 and beyond (including src.rpm and debuginfo
packages), see CentOS Stream mirror. For archived content from EOL
releases, see Vault mirror and Debuginfo mirror

So you should migrate from CentOS to other distribution
